# trigger a function with onInput intypescript/React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to trigger my function elevatorCalc when some numbers are entered in my form field.

```
const elevatorCalc = () => {
console.log("test")
};
```

I'm trying something like this using onInput but I cant see "test" in my console

```
                        <div className="col-md-4" id="number-of-apartments">
                            <label htmlFor="residential_apartments">Number of apartments *</label>
                            <input onInput={() => {elevatorCalc}} required type="number" id="resinput_number-of-apartments" />
                        </div>
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You're not calling the function at the moment. `onInput={() => {elevatorCalc}}` needs to be `onInput={() => {elevatorCalc()}}` (or `onInput={elevatorCalc}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a starting point. Note how I pass `onInput` directly the function name as

`onInput={elevatorCalc}`

That function receives an HTML Event as input, which I named `e`
You can access its current value by using `e.target.value`

```js
const App = (props) => {
  
  const elevatorCalc = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="col-md-4" id="number-of-apartments">
      <label htmlFor="residential_apartments">Number of apartments *</label>
      <input onInput={elevatorCalc} required type="number" id="resinput_number-of-apartments" />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```